# SFTP user should be able to access only a sub directory in ChrootDirectory

Tags: sftp

My sshd_config file is configured like this:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User shiv
ChrootDirectory /var/www/html/
ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /Sub_Directory
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

User shiv is able to connect and the session starts with `/Sub_Directory`. When user tries to access directory `/home` or `/var/www/html` in Remote site Address Bar on FileZilla it shows error "Failed to retrieve directory listing" That's fine and I want same. **But when user types `/` only in Remote site Address Bar it lists the content of html folder which is `ChrootDirectory /var/www/html/` while I have defined a Directory for that user `ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /Sub_Directory`  I want it should show error when type `/` User should not be able to access this.**

I want to manage it with SFTP only.
Owner of html folder is `root:root` with 755. The `Sub_Directory` is inside of `html` Directory.

Comment: How about `chmod 751 /var/www/html/` or `chmod 711 /var/www/html/`? You may also do a `chmod o-rwx /var/www/html/*` and/or `chmod g-rwx /var/www/html/*`.

Comment: Yes, It worked for me - chmod 751 /var/www/html/